# Rails send four backslashes using Net::HTTP

Tags: php, json, ruby-on-rails-4, net-http

My rails application need to send some data to a php application, which expects a POST call.
I use the folowing code:

```
uri = URI.parse(apiUrl)
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.to_s, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})

req.basic_auth(api_key, token)
req.set_form_data({"action" => action, "data" => data})

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(req)
```

Where data is a hash converted to json:

```
data = {
  :key1 => val1,
  :key2 => val2
}.to_json
```

(it is a nested hash, i.e. some values are hash as well)

My problem is that the php application receives 4 backslashes before each quotation mark:

```
$data_json = $_POST['data'];
error_log($data_json);
```

and in error log I see:

```
'{\\\\"key1\\\\":val1,\\\\"key2\\\\":\\\\"val2\\\\"}'
```

Looks like rails add one of them, but even if I remove it and replace it with the following code:

```
a.gsub!(/\"/, '\'')
```

I still get many backslashes inside the php application, **hence cannot convert the string to array**.

Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `set_form_data` net/http is POSTing the form as urlencoded. Its NOT posting your request body as pure JSON.

If you want to POST raw JSON you will need to follow a pattern like:

```
uri = URI('https://myapp.com/api/v1/resource')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
req.body = {param1: 'some value', param2: 'some other value'}.to_json
res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(req)
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks! One thing for those who find it helpful - in order to get the json in the php application you should retrieve it from the body using: `$body = file_get_contents('php://input');`